# Deploying a React.js app with a Express.js backend api point on AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, nginx

I have created a React.js application and also developed an API endpoint for the backend using Express.js and Node. I want to deploy this application to Amazon ECS but don't know the best practice to do so.

Currently I am using an EC2 instance which I installed MySQL and Nginx on and I serve the frontend with nginx and route the urls beginning with /api to the port of my Express server. I was looking into deploying this on AWS ECS but have ran into some questions that have confused me about what path to take.

Q1. I have seen examples on internet of people doing seperate containers for frontend and backend and also saw some doing all of it in one container. In terms of scale or standard practice, is it a better idea to containerize both the frontend and backend into one container and also have nginx in the same container serving the application? In that case how do I handle databases if I were to have multiple container of the same app deployed?

Q2. Is there a way for me to have a container of both backend and frontend and have the backend communicate with Amazon RDS?

Q3. Is it better to serve the frontend from S3 bucket and just have the backend in a container that connects to Amazon RDS behind a VPC?

Q4. What I should look for and how should I handle this in terms of automatic test and deployment? does any of the methods above make deployment easier or more complicated?

Thank you very much.